# MySQL: Joining a table on a field that could be NULL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (Releases and Formats) and a field that is linked to both of them - `bar_code`. The problem I am having is with this select statement:

```
SELECT
    Release.name,
    Release.default_upc,
    Artist.name,
    Artist.url_name,
    Format.*
FROM
    releases AS Release,
    artists AS Artist,
    formats AS Format
WHERE
    Release.id IN(20015, 2414) AND
    Artist.id = Release.artist_id AND
    Format.bar_code = Release.default_upc
```

The issue is that when `Release.default_upc = null`, no record will be returned. However, it is a valid behavior that `default_upc` can be null, and if it is the query should *not* attempt to look for a Format with `Format.bar_code = null` - instead just returning the other selected data.

Not actually sure this is 100% possible in MySQL, but open to any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Outer Joins.

[One site that explains](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html)

[Another one](http://mysql-tips.blogspot.com/2005/04/mysql-outer-join-sql-tutorialexamples.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join...here's a quick shot. Check the other links for explanation.

```
select Release.name,
       Release.default_upc,
       Artist.name,
       Artist.url_name,
       Format.*
from releases as Release
inner join artists as Artist
    on Artist.id = Release.artist_id
outer join formats as Format
    on Format.bar_code = Release.default_upc
where
    Release.id in (20015, 2414)
```